# Django does not let me pass empty fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In my forms I have a table with the following columns:

```
type = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
terms = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

but when I don't enter anything for bio, it gives me an error message with `[23000][1048] Column 'bio' cannot be null`.

Why is this?

Comment: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I have, yet nothing changed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the _full_ error traceback to it.

Comment: if you have `forms.py` please share.

Answer (score 0):

for your bio, user TextField that let you null and black by default.
as far as i see, this is your model. Please include your form for this if you have made.